# How to get Angular CLI to generate *.less files

Tags: angular-cli

When I use the Angular 5 CLI to generate a new component (e.g. ng g c my-component) it creates 4 files (html, css, ts, spec.ts). I would prefer to also (or instead) create a *.less file for the component. I'm not sure where Angular stores the file list or template that it uses to generate the new files. Can I add my own file types to be generated by the CLI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Couple of things you can do to make this happen.

First, when you create a new project, use the `--style` option to set the default style format to *less*.

```
ng new new-app --style=less
```

This way, when you create new components, the default style format files created will be less (.less files).

Second, *if you have an existing application*, you can change the default in the *.angular-cli.json*. To do this, find the `defaults` section in the file, and change the `styleExt` values to `less`. See below.

```
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "less", 
  "component": {}
}
```

That is all there is to it!

Answer (score 4):

For Angular 8 use below setting in your angular.json

```
"@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "less"
        }
```

Example:

```
 "YOURAppName": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "less"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Angular 9** and higher use "**style**" instead ("**styleext**" or "**styleExt**")

on `angular.json`:

```
"@schematics/angular:component": {
  "style": "less"
}
```

Comment: We just upgraded to Angular 9, and now the CLI is generating CSS files instead of LESS files.  This answer fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

For **Angular 8**:

on `angular.json`:

```
"@schematics/angular:component": {
  "styleext": "less"
}
```